# $(<input/>).attr({ xxxxxxxxx}).html();

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to create an "input" on the fly and turn it to a string.

```
$(<input/>).attr({ xxxxxxxxx}).html();
```

the above code keeps returning empty string.

Basically the string will be returned in JQGrid's formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will not work in this scenario as it returns `innerHTML`, but the input element does not have it, you need to use [.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)

You need to try

```
$('<input/>').attr({ xxxxxxxxx}).get(0).outerHTML
```

also

```
$('<input/>', { xxxxxxxxx}).get(0).outerHTML
```

Comment: accepted answer.. just curious how can I set the TEXT for the input and will doing it this way affect performance?

Comment: @user4127n what do you mean by TEXT, did you mean value?

Comment: yup value. basically the display text.. the type is actually radio <input type="radio">TEXT</input>